# why does create-expo-app not work even after installing node and all it's dependencies?

Tags: expo

I am trying to create a project using the create-expo-app command but constantly get an error even though I have tried so many ways of correcting it.

```
C:\Users\Abdul Ghani>npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs@49
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Abdul Ghani\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Abdul Ghani\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

This is the error I recieve

Can someone help me with this please

Comment: Create the directory `C:\Users\Abdul Ghani\AppData\Roaming\npm`. Not sure why it wasn't created automatically.